# Find a text in a range and copy the next Activecell.offset(1,1)16 cells to destination

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range I13 to I6076. I am starting at first I13 cell and finding a match in `Range("D12:D103333")`. If it finds a match in Col D then it should offset `Activecell.offset(1,1)` from Col D cell and copy the next 16 cells(vertical copy) to corresponding I13 row(horizontal paste). and then move on to I14 and so on. I have created a do while loop to find the cells in the range `Range("D12:D103333")`, but how do I offset and copy the next 16 cells. and then go to next cell in col I.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many Thanks. Code is below.

```
Sub Kantar()

    Dim Category As String
    i As Integer
    
    Range("I13").Select
    Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        Category = ActiveCell.Value
        Range("D12:D103333").Find(What:=Category, MatchCase:=True).Select
           
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

1) Once the cell is found, `activecell.offset(1,1)`

2) From there, use your `activecell.address` and `activecell.address + 16` as a range to do `range.copy`

3) Offset the active cell to where you want to paste.

4) Paste Special with transpose to transpose it horizontally (use macro recorder to show you how if you are unsure)

5) Offset back to original cell (coordinates based on where you end up)

6) Offset down 1 cell and continue the loop. (Which you already have coded)

I'd give actual code but I'm not at a PC. Hopefully these steps still help if someone else doesn't give you the code :)

Comment: HI Busse, thank you for this logic. I have actually modified my code to use for loop rather than do while as below,

Comment: Sub Kantar()

    Dim Category As String
    Rng As Range, MyCell As Range
    
    Set Rng = Range("I13:I6086")
    For Each MyCell In Rng
        Category = MyCell.Value
        Range("D12:D103333").Find(What:=Category, MatchCase:=True).Select
            
    
    Next MyCell


End Sub

Comment: Either or, `For` or `Do` should work for you in this instance.  I won't be at a PC for a few hours so see if you can make any changes using the notes I provided. Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for the Brilliant Logic Busse!! I have managed to create a running Macro using your steps. But as its looping through thousands of cells its very slow and think it will take couple of hours running through. Is there any way I can make it more efficient. My code is below, Many thanks!!

Comment: Sub Kantar()

    Dim Category As String
    Dim Rng As Range, MyCell As Range
    
    Set Rng = Range("I13:I6086")
    For Each MyCell In Rng
        Category = MyCell.Value
        Range("D12:D103333").Find(What:=Category, MatchCase:=True).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
        Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 15, 5)).Copy
        MyCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Next MyCell
End Sub

Comment: Glad to hear! One possible tip would be at the start add `Application.Screenupdating = False` and towards the end add an `Application.Screenupdating = True`. It's not a replacement for efficient coding, but it's sure to speed it up. Try it out, and if my answer helped, don't forget to mark it as the right answer :)

Comment: Many Thanks!! That has already made a big difference! Yes you gave a brilliant answer, so all marked!

Comment: Woo-Hoo! Glad you got it. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would like to Thank Busse for providing me the logical steps to get my answer. It was Super helpful. So I am copying my code below which might help several users with similar issues. Thanks:))

```
Sub Kantar2()

    Dim Category As String, i As Long, FinalRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range, MyCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    i = 10
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("I13:I6086")
    For Each MyCell In Rng
        Category = MyCell.Value
        Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(FinalRow, 4)).Find(What:=Category, MatchCase:=True).Select
        i = ActiveCell.Row
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
        Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 15, 5)).Copy
        MyCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Next MyCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```